# how to set a this.var from a class inside a function that's in that class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I want to set the **this.session** variable from within the last **this.rpc** via this.setSession() but this is 't working for me:

anyone got an answer for me? I'm still learning javascript classes and coming from php classes, it suprises me that this is'nt working.

```
function glpirpc(host,user,pass){
    this.host = host;
    this.session = "";
    this.user = user;
    this.password = pass;
    this.setSession = function(s){
            this.session = s;
    }
    this.rpc = function(method,params,callback) {
            var args = {};
            args.host = this.host;
            console.log('session:' + this.session);
            if (this.session != ""){
                    console.log('get session');
                    this.host += "?session=" + this.session;
            }
            args.session = _this.session;
            args.method = method;
            args.params = params;
            $.post('glpirpc/',args,function(data){
                    if (typeof data.error != "undefined"){
                            alert(data.error);
                    }else {
                            callback(data.return)
                            }
            },"json");
    }
    this.rpc('glpi.doLogin',{
                            'login_name': this.user,
                            'login_password': this.password,
                            },function(data){
                                    this.setSession(data.session)
                            });
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strange thing about "methods" in JavaScript is that their `this` object can be anything or nothing, and its value depends only on how the function is called, not whether it's called from another method.  When you do `callback(data.return)`, that's a plain function call, not a method call, so it doesn't get a `this` object.

Instead do `callback.call(this, data.return)` so that the callback is invoked with the same `this` object as the function that called it.

---

To elaborate a little:  when you write something like `myobject.mymethod()` in JavaScript, two things happen:  first the interpreter looks up the `mymethod` property of `myobject`, and then calls it with `myobject` as the context.  It's equivalent to writing `myobject.mymethod.call(myobject)`.  But when you use a function's `call()` method, you can specify a *different* context object — e.g. `myobject1.mymethod.call(myobject2)`, which will find the function via `myobject1`, but when the function runs, its `this` will be `myobject2`.

When you call a plain function, not on an object — `callback(data.return)` as opposed to `someobject.callback(data.return)` — its context will be the global `window` object.  And  you can't call it with `this.callback(data.return)` because the function isn't stored as a property of the `this` object.  So instead you use `callback.call(this, data.return)` to specify that the current function's context (its `this`) should also be the context in which the callback runs.

Comment: What if the provider of the callback needed a different context? It seems wrong to assume that every callback should execute using rpc()'s context.

Comment: It seems to be what's desired in this example, and it's a reasonable default:  the callback will run in the context of whatever object `glpirpc()` was called on.  If an external caller wants to use a different context for its callback, there are ways to write a function that overrides its context with a different one, and JS libraries typically have helper functions to make it easy to do that.

Comment: (For example, the `jQuery.proxy()` function, mentioned in another answer.)

Comment: Wow, thanks for the fantastic explanation! I didn't know about the call() function. I'm going to try this out tomorrow.

And to clarify the callback, This is an rpc client, so the callback will be doing stuff with the returned data.

Another question: With the explained call() function, can I set the this.session variable directly from the callback function, or do I still need to use the this.setSession() function?

Comment: The `session` variable and the `setSession()` function are both stored in the same object, so both are accessible whenever you have a reference to that object.  `this.session` and `this.setSession()` should both work from within the callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery.proxy()` for this.

```
   this.rpc('glpi.doLogin',{
           'login_name': this.user,
           'login_password': this.password,
       },
       $.proxy(function(data) {
           this.setSession(data.session)
       }, this));
```